# How do I allow full HTML while rendering a view?

Tags: views, 8

Some HTML code like `<iframe>` is stripped out. How can I allow full HTML in a view?

```
    $options = array(
        'id' => 'area_text_custom',
        'table' => 'views',
        'field' => 'area_text_custom',
        'relationship' => 'none',
        'group_type' => 'none',
        'admin_label' => '',
        'empty' => TRUE,
        'tokenize' => FALSE,
        'content' => "My HTML Code with <iframe ... >",
        'plugin_id' => 'text_custom',

    );
    $view->setHandler('page_1', 'footer', 'area_text_custom', $options);
```

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this same problem in the past, and I think your best option is to take care of this from a template.

Create an applicable template for your view (field, row, etc) and define your html in there. The template options/naming conventions aren't as clearly outlined in D8 as they were in D7, but [here is the documentation page](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.theme.inc/group/views_templates/8.2.x) for Views templates. The comments have some helpful links and naming conventions for different types of templates depending on your needs.

Since it seems like you're trying to add your iFrame to the View's footer, you'd probably want to use the `views-view.html.twig` template. Naming conventions for this template are:

```
views-view--foobar--page.html.twig
views-view--page.html.twig
views-view--foobar.html.twig
views-view.html.twig
```

You'll want to copy `/your_site_root/core/modules/views/templates/views-view.html.twig` into the `templates` (or `templates/views`) folder of your theme. You'll then want to print your custom code inside the `<footer></footer>` tags of the template.

If you need more flexibility with what gets printed in the template, you can send variables into your template using [`template_preprocess_views_view`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!views!views.theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_views_view/8.2.x).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest having your view display "content" of type "teaser" which would then allow you to use a twig template file such as node--content-type--teaser.html.twig.

This way you can add whatever markup you want to the twig file... even iFrames.

If you must have fields, for instance in exposed filters combine, remember you can "force" use fields in views :)